# Python in Command Prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

I was attempting to download some libraries recently, and the tutorial called for me to ensure Python had been downloaded properly. As a precaution, I went to the Windows Command Prompt, and typed in 'python', just as the tutorial said. Once I pressed enter, however, I was brought to a Microsoft Store page where I had the option to download Python 3.8. The Store page opened by itself. This was not one of the scenarios addressed by the tutorial. What does this mean?

I am running Python 3.5 and Windows 10. If someone could help me out, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the directory in which Python is installed on your PATH environment variable?

Comment: You have to define python in your PATH

Comment: I suggest you go to https://www.python.org and download a Python exe installer, then run it. Among other things, it will ask if you want Python added to your `PATH` as well as install the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#python-launcher-for-windows) utility.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Apps and Features", click on "App execution aliases", put both Python-related aliases to "Off".

[image]